# Concatenate only when all values are true in mysql

Tags: mysql

The following is the query I have used to concatenate siretagprefix and siretagsec

```
CONCAT('TZN',
            `adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`siretagprefix`,
            `adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`siretagsec`) AS `siretagid`,
```

The result of the query when siretagprefix and siretagsec when the values are null, I get TZN as the result. How can I concatenate only when all the values are true.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CASE` to check your column values

```
CASE WHEN `adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`siretagprefix` IS NOT NULL
      AND `adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`siretagsec` IS NOT NULL
THEN
    CONCAT('TZN',
                `adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`siretagprefix`,
                `adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`siretagsec`)
ELSE NULL END AS siretagid
```

Comment: i still get the same result, why could that be the case @M khalid Junaid

Comment: @MirieriMogaka Make sure you have `NULL` in your columns not empty string or spaces, It would be good if you can add some sample data set for your table

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `case` expression:

```
CASE WHEN `adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`siretagprefix` IS NOT NULL AND
          `adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`siretagsec`    IS NOT NULL
     THEN CONCAT('TZN',
                 `adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`siretagprefix`,
                 `adggtnz`.`reg04_rpt_animreg`.`siretagsec`)
END AS `siretagid`
```